# Log hangfire events using existing serilog

Tags: hangfire, serilog

Im new to hangfire, and im trying to setup a way to log the events using my existing serilog logger in an asp.net web api. Here is my logger class:

```
public static class LoggerInitializer
{
    private static ILogger CreateLog()
    {
        var settings = Settings.Instance;
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().
            MinimumLevel.Debug().
            WriteTo.RollingFile(settings.LoggerDebugDirectory +"Debug-{Date}.txt", restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug, 
                outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}").
            WriteTo.RollingFile(settings.LoggerVerboseDirectory + "Debug-{Date}.txt").
            CreateLogger();
        return Log.Logger;
    }
    static ILogger _logger;
    public static ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        if (_logger != null)
            return _logger;
        return _logger = CreateLog();
    }
}
```

and in my startup file I add the code from the hangfire documentation:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage(Settings.Instance.NLSContextConnectionString);

        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();
```

My hangfire works perfectly, but how do i enable make hangfire use my serilog?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/configuring-logging.html), Hangfire automatically supports logging to Serilog.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: no it is not, sadly. and i find the documentation really lacking.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but the lack of a `Log.CloseAndFlush()` call at application exit will cause problems (unless it's simply omitted from your code sample). Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that Hangfire is initializing and caching its own internal logger *before* `CreateLog()` is being called by the application.

To test this theory, try moving the code that initializes `Log.Logger` to the very beginning of the app's startup code, e.g. in `Global.Application_Start()` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

In Hangfire 1.6.19 (and maybe before that, I did not check) adding the NuGet Package to your project gives you an extension method on `IGlobalConfiguration` :

`configuration.UseSerilogLogProvider();`